# How do I print the output only after keying in all the inputs, instead of having it printed line by line?

Tags: java, tostring

I have an Employee class:

```
public class Employee{
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double salary;
  private double rate;

  public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, double salary){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.salary = salary;
  }

  public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
  }

  public double getSalary(){
    return salary/1000;
  }

  public double setSalaryIncrease(double rate){
    if ((rate-1)*100>=0){
      this.rate = ((rate-1)*100);
      return this.rate;
    }
    else{
      this.rate = -((rate-1)*100);
      return this.rate;
    }
  }

  public String toString(){
    return firstName+" "+lastName+": salary is "+String.format("%.0f", salary/1000)+"K, annual raise is "+String.format("%.0f", rate)+"%";
  }
}
```

and in my Main class,

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      Employee employee = new Employee(sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.nextDouble());
      employee.setSalaryIncrease(sc.nextDouble());
      System.out.println(employee);
    }
  }
}
```

For example, if I have a list of inputs e.g.

```
Mohammad Ali 24000.0 1.11
Steve Gates 36000.0 1.05
Michael Jordan 71000.0 1.07
```

I want it to be printed only after all 3 inputs have been scanned. However, I end up getting each line printed after each line is scanned i.e.

- Mohammad Ali 24000.0 1.11

  **Mohammad Ali: salary is 24K, annual raise is 11%**
- Steve Gates 36000.0 1.05

  **Steve Gates: salary is 36K, annual raise is 5%**

How do I modify my toString() method to print all out as a whole after reading all the inputs, without making changes to my main class?

Comment: You need to add the `Employee` objects to a `List`, then when the while is done you can proceed to print the `Employee.toString` in a for each loop.

Comment: You can't change behavior of the program without making changes of its code.

Comment: Hmmms, it is the requirements not to make modifications to the Main class, and strictly only the Employee class, so I was wondering if there's a way to add the employee object within the employee class instead? @KenBekov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.out.println(); prints every string in new line

try System.out.print("string") 
and after the while loop you can use 
System.out.println("") to tab to the new line